# How to show schema definition on OpenApi/Haskell?

Tags: haskell, schema, openapi

I'm going to convert Haskell's ADT to JSON Schema with Library from [`openapi3`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/openapi3-3.2.3/docs/Data-OpenApi-Schema.html)

code :

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}     
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module JSchema (Size)
    where

import Control.Lens
import Data.Proxy
import Data.OpenApi
import Types
import Deal
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Data.Aeson.TH
import Data.Aeson.Types

import Data.Ratio ((%))
import Data.Fixed

data Unit = Inch
          | Meter
          deriving (Show, Generic)

data Size = Balance Unit Int 
          | Balance2 Float
          | Size 
          deriving (Show, Generic)

instance ToSchema Size
$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''Size)
instance ToSchema Unit
$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''Unit)
```

if the type was rendered to JSON Schema by :

```
encodePretty $ toSchema $ (Proxy :: Proxy Size)
```

it returned expected, but it only generates a `$ref` points to  `Unit`, it doesn't contain any definition on `Unit`.

How to show the caller the all information on this schema ? The goal is let user know the schema and user would know how to build a json request , without knowing `Unit` he won't able to build a valid json object.

I tried with `toInlinedSchema` it will blow up memory as I'm using recursive types in other ADT.

```
{
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "contents": {
          "items": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Unit"   // <<<<-PROBLEM HERE
            },
            {
              "maximum": 9223372036854775807,
              "type": "integer",
              "minimum": -9223372036854775808
            }
          ],
          "maxItems": 2,
          "type": "array",
          "minItems": 2
        },
        "tag": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [
            "Balance"
          ]
        }
 ....
}
```

Comment: I can't answer this question, but I think that if you posted your code as text, possibly making a minimal complete example, maybe someone else can cut & paste it on their own machine and try to fix it. In general, we recommend to avoid posting code as pictures.

Comment: It's not very clear from the docs, but it seems you can use `declareSchema` in combination with `Data.OpenApi.Declare.runDeclare`. The type of `\proxy -> runDeclare (declareSchema proxy) Data.Monoid.mempty` is `ToSchema a => Data.Proxy.Proxy a -> (Definitions Schema, Schema)`, where `Definitions` is a kind of map: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/openapi3-3.2.3/docs/Data-OpenApi-Internal.html#t:Definitions If you are using Servant, another option is to document your entire API with https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-openapi3